# How can I append a new value to an existing array from a different swiftui file?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I've got a project where I have a different view controller (a modual) where when I press the "Add" button I'd like to append to a List. I have the modual vc in a different SwiftUI file.

I was wondering how can I append to the already exisiting array from the different vc file. I've included my code from both files. Which includes what I've already tried.

**ContentView File**

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    struct Driving: Identifiable, Hashable{
        let name: String
        let id = UUID()
    }
    
    @State public var drivingList = [
        Driving(name: "Hello World"),
        Driving(name: "Matt")
    ]

    @State private var multiSelection = Set<UUID>()
    
    @State public var isShowingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(drivingList, selection: $multiSelection){
                Text($0.name)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Driving Logbook")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Test Add with date", action: {
                    addWithDate()
                });
                EditButton();
                Button(action: {
                    isShowingSheet.toggle()
                },
                       label: {
                    Label("Add", systemImage: "plus.app")
                }).sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet, content: {
                    AddLogbookView()
                });
            }
        }
    
        
    }
    
    func didDismiss(){
        
    }
    
    func addWithDate(){
        let dateNow = Date.now
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
        drivingList.append(Driving(name: dateFormatter.string(from: dateNow)))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**AddLogbook SwiftUI File - Modual VC**

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddLogbookView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var sometext: String = ""
    
   @State public var pubDrivingL = ContentView().drivingList
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            TextField(
                "Test",
                text: $sometext
            )
                .navigationBarTitle("Add Log", displayMode: .inline)
                .toolbar{
                    ToolbarItem(placement:.navigationBarLeading){
                        Button(action: {
                            ContentView().isShowingSheet.toggle()
                            dismiss()
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Cancel").bold()
                        })
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(){
                        Button(action: {
                            pubDrivingL.append(ContentView.Driving(name: "Test"))
                            print("View")
                            ContentView().isShowingSheet.toggle()
                            dismiss()
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Add").bold()
                        })
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct AddLogbookView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddLogbookView()
    }
}
```

I've tried referencing the array in a var or just by simply referencing the ContentView vc and then the array itself. I was expecting that when I press the "Add" button it would append a value to the exisiting array.

Obviously I'm missing something here, and am currently learning SwiftUI, so if possible would love if answers could be explained if possible please and thank you!!

Comment: You are creating a new list in the sheet view, not referencing the original (the whole concept here is wrong).  You need to bind the property in the child view to the property in the parent view.  Research `bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to propagating the data from the parent view to the child view  isn't how it's done in SwiftUI.  You need to use bindings to share the data.

A very simplified example that shows the approach is below:

```
struct ChildView: View {
   @Binding var textToEdit: String
   var body: some View {
      TextField("Edit me", text: $textToEdit)
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State var showSheet  = false
   @State var myText = "Some text"
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Text(myText)
         Button("Click to edit") {
            showSheet = true
         }
         .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            ChildView(textToEdit: $myText)  //inject a binding to the String property
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

This is a bare bones approach, but if you click the button, edit the text, and pull down the sheet to dismiss you will see the changes have been passed back through to the `@State` property in the parent view.